# Whats wrong with this angular2 unit test setup?

Tags: angular

```
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Calculator } from '../classes/calculator';
import { tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing/fake_async';
import { inject, TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing/test_bed';

describe('SearchService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: Calculator, useClass: Calculator}
      ]
    });
  });
});
```

It throws errors on 'describe' and 'beforeEach' saying it can't find the names.  I've read that you don't need to import these anymore in RC5, but something is still wrong.  I've installed the latest jasmine, and karma packages.

Comment: Have you installed TypeScript definition file for Jasmine?

Comment: yes, I installed them along with the latest of jasmine and karma.

Comment: Strange, `describe` and `beforeEach` are defined in Jasmine TypeScript definition file. I successfully use the same your code [here](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization/blob/master/test/pipes/translate.pipe.spec.ts). Try comparing the other environment settings.

Comment: @robisim74 I've redone the structure based on the angular cli and the test in the app directory testing the app component runs fine.  However any test in a subdirectory does not.  Is there a setting that needs to change somewhere to tell it to find the files wherever they are?

Comment: If TypeScript compiler does not find the names, `typings` as `globalDependencies` or new `@types` via npm should be enough. If you have other errors, you should check the configuration files of Karma.